# What is the name of this property of a function?

Tags: function, terminology

Suppose that you have a function f: List a -> a such that f is associative and f(x, y, z) === f(x, f(y, z)). Is there a conventional name for this latter property?

Examples of functions with this property are AND, XOR, sum, product, and GCD. Examples of associative functions without this property are NAND and XNOR.

I believe that the property is equivalent to saying that f(xs) === reduce(f, xs).

Comment: I have never heard of any nomenclature on that front.  **Name It**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is also equivalent to saying that f is a catamorphism of an associative binary function and its neutral element. Doesn't exactly roll off the tongue.

(Also, NAND is not associative. My bad.)